# Overriding Login Error Messages

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, controller

I have an AuthController, where I have extended the getCredentials method so the user needs to be both existant and active to be able to login. This is the method:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request) {
  $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
  return array_add($credentials, 'status', '1');
}
```

I would also like the failed login messages to be different, depending on whether or not the user is active, so the user knows if he is failing his username / password, or just because he hasn't activated his account yet.

I could override the login method of the `AuthenticatesUser` trait, but it seems overkill to duplicate all the logic just to change that.

Can I extend the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method to make some sort of validation there, based on the previous Auth::guard->attempt() call? I mean, does that method leave any information behind that allows me to know, after the call has been made, what made the attempt return false?

Or how would I approach this, without having to override a method completely just to make a simple validation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user ) {

   // The user was authenticated check if it the active column is true or not
   if($user->active == false){
      //Store some flash message here saying he's not account is not active
      //Log him out after.
      Auth::logout();
   }
  return redirect()->intended( $this->redirectPath() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) works perfectly! I actually removed the adding of 'status' in the getCredentials method, and added your code, returning a reditect with an error inside the if.

Comment: Don't forget to log him out though or else if you redirect him to the login page again, the middleware will be triggered again. Logout will automatically redirects him to the login page so no need for that